# Python pode ser usada pra trabalhos pesados?

Tags: python, desempenho

Bom dia,
Eu sei que python não é uma linguagem mto performática (visa mais a simplicidade) [Um exemplo aqui](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/php.html). Mas ela aguenta o tranco? Por exemplo em servidores grandes com muita carga como o Facebook, sites de banco etc. Ela se daria bem? Seria viável usar ela? E para aplicações desktop?
Obrigado.

Comment: ao perguntar uma questão de performance você deve ser o mais específico possível. Qual a situação que você quer utilizar python? Outro ponto é que se você está comparando performance você precisa saber o que você está comparando python contra. Da forma como está a pergunta é muito genérica e não tem como dar uma resposta pra ela.

Comment: O [Google ja utiliza Python em sua infraestrutura](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/r3Wj6RoD7Bg), entretanto, não da para dar uma resposta, depende do objetivo que vc pretende alcançar com a linguagem.

Comment: Aguentar o tranco tem mais a ver com a arquitetura e infraestrutura que você usa do que só com a linguagem de programação. Também vale lembrar que um sistema não precisa ser todo feito em uma mesma linguagem de programação. Um dos pontos fortes das linguagens dinâmicas como Python é justamente a facilidade de interagir com código escrito em outras linguagens.

Comment: O Google usa Python desde o início, quando os primeiros Googlers (Sergey, Larry, Craig, ...) tomaram uma decisão inteligente: "Python onde podemos, C++ onde devemos". Sabemos que o Instagram é _powered by_ Python + Django também. Além disso é possível compilar software Python em C com o Cython, deixando eles virtualmente tão rápidos quanto um programa em C.